In Reformed Theology how are baptism and circumcision of an infant comparable?
When talking to my generally reformed friends on the topic of pedo-baptism they often say that baptism is the new circumcision, circumcision was done on babies to bring them into the Old Covenant, therefore we baptize babies to bring them into the New Covenant.
I have a hard time with this because before infant circumcision was not based on the faith of the child but on the parents and their adherents to God's command to do so. But in the New Covenant, this same theological truth does not apply. I can not come into the covenant unintentionally or outside of my will.
I am sure Reformed Theology has an answer to this and I just have not seen it yet, so how would Reformed Theology answer this?

It should be noted that this connection is made explicitly in the Bible itself, see Colossians 2:11-12. Whether the implication to pedo baptism is legitimate is a different question, of course

Welcome to C.SE.  There are indeed TWO camps within Reformed Protestantism: the Baptists and those who allow infant baptism.  Generally, the latter will ALSO include catechism and Confirmation to make sure that the youths who were baptized as infants (I was one of them) know their faith and have opportunity to make their faith known publicly.  So, post-confirmation, the result is the same as Baptists.

This is a good question for a new contributor, so, thanks for it, and welcome! Tomorrow I should be able to consult Reformed paedo-baptist writings to give their answer, and trust you will keep this question open for another 16 or 17 hours. Given that circumcision of eight-day-old male babies never included female babies, I will be keen to check for any comment on that apparent anomaly.

@Anne found two helpful articles from a paedobaptist church on whether baptism confers grace in its act and whether it removes original sin and on its relationship with OT circumcision and OT/NT covenant.

The question asks how baptism and circumcision of an infant can be comparable (in Reformed theology). I will strive to stick purely to that one point, using Reformed writing in a book by a renowned Reformed, Presbyterian scholar. In the margins of his book I have written scribbles, due to the perplexity I had when reading the reasons. I may add a scribble or two, if it relates to reasoning about this comparison. But I will endeavour to present the Reformed stance without bias.
First, this is how the author summarises his chapter on baptism. (Necessary to quote, to avoid common misunderstandings.) Then I will quote his points about how he compares circumcision with infant baptism.

"Why do I baptise children? Is it because I believe that the infants
of all believing parents are elect? No! Is it because I believe that
the infants of believing parents will all one day be born again? No!
Is it because I believe that one day they will all accept God for
themselves? No! It is because God gave me an ordinance: Put the sign
of the spiritual covenant on the physical seed." A Faith to Live By,
p.219 Donald Macleod, Christian Focus, 1998

That last sentence is key to answering the question asked here. Macleod goes on to explain:

"At the very beginning of this arrangement [circumcision] God put
Ishmael and Esau there to remind us that we were not to do this on the
ground that we know theologically how the thing [baptism of infants]
worked. We were to do it because God said it. In the case of Ishmael
and Esau it seemed not to work. It wasn't related to any rationale of
its effectiveness. It was done (and it is still to be done) on the
ground that God said, 'Put the sign of my promise not only on
yourselves but also on your children'." (Ibid. pp.219-21)

This brings in Confessional Covenant Theology, which is then briefly explained thus:

"First, infant baptism is given on the basis of the qualifications of
the parent, not the qualifications of the child. It is given to the
parent, and it is the parent's relationship with God that is the
decisive factor... the parent who comes receives it because he or she
is in a special relationship with God.
Secondly, we should not give the sacrament of baptism to a man for his
child unless we would be prepared to give it to him for himself... I
cannot baptise his infant if I would not be prepared to baptise
himself. And on what grounds could I baptise him? According to
Confessional theology, I can baptise him if he is a member of that
visible church; that is, if he professes the true faith... if he
receives and rest on Christ alone for salvation...
Go back to the meaning of baptism. It signifies union with Christ;
and, implied in that, the washing away of guilt and corruption,
baptism in the Holy Spirit and a pledge of commitment to God... In the
Old Testament the general principle was that the sacraments were the
privilege of covenant-keepers. Within covenant-keeping there might
sometimes be a great deal of spiritual mediocrity. Spiritual
mediocrity, however, was one thing. Covenant repudiation was quite
another. There was no circumcision and no passover for the
covenant-repudiator. He was cut off from the people. In the same way,
in the New Testament church there can be no infant baptism for the
covenant repudiator. Baptism (and the Lord's Supper) are for those who
can claim to be keeping God's covenant." (Ibid. pp.220-221)

Earlier on in that chapter on baptism as it relates to circumcision, the claim was made that in Abraham's case it was a sign of a spiritual covenant; that the core promise was that God would be his God and the God of his seed. Circumcision was the sign of that promise (with scriptures quoted in support). He adds that the circumcised and the baptised need to be born again. Then he argues that non-baptised children of believers are still covenant-children, even though the sign of baptism is not [yet] upon them. Children do not come into the covenant because of the sign itself. The believing parent also wants the sign of that covenant relationship upon his family. Now I quote again:

"Under the Old Testament, parents had the privilege of hearing God
say, 'Take your children, too, and put the sign [circumcision] upon
them: the sign that God's promise is to them as well. Put the sign
that God's promise is to them as well'." (Ibid. p.218).

My scribble - But only the boys, though! Nothing is said in the chapter about the anomaly of only male babies getting the sign of the covenant - circumcision.
Another scribble - Circumcising males does not represent the baptism of males and females therefore circumcision must figure something else: which it does - the birth of sons by a means in which flesh has been cut off. Redemption brings in sonship and the sons of God are realised in a birth that is not of nature but is of water and spirit, that is from above (anothen); that is, of God; that is an again-birth (paligennisis); that is a new birth (anagennesis). This is what circumcision figures.
However, the author seems to argue that a physical sign on males was a sign of being in God's covenant with Abraham, which covenant extended to Gentiles in the New Covenant in Christ. And that water baptism should be given to children of Christian believers because the sign of the spiritual covenant can go on the physical seed. If I have understood him aright.
This means that your paedo-baptist friends who said "circumcision was done on babies to bring them into the Old Covenant, therefore we baptize babies to bring them into the New Covenant" were wrong, according to this professor of Reformed theology. He argues that circumcision and baptism were signs upon children of those already in either the Old or the New Covenants, meaning those children were also Covenant-children. The problem remains, however, that an uncircumcised male child in Israel who remained uncircumcised was never viewed as part of the Covenant community. And, in the New Testament (Covenant), it is the spiritual new birth that brings one into the New Covenant, of which water baptism is but a sign that this has happened. And a sign points to the reality, which is spiritual new birth of a believer having taken place by the power of the Holy Spirit.

"Go back to the meaning of baptism. It signifies union with Christ" seems to be the key point here. Baptism is a purely symbolic ritual.

@Anne As you must know already, answers need to address the perspective asked, but you haven't included the concept of "household" that is key to confessional Reformed understanding of circumcision as entrance to covenant, which resolved (among other things) the inclusion of girls.  Compare this explanation.

@GratefulDisciple  The point of 'household' never came into the OPs question; it's important in Reformed theology but was never mentioned in the book I quoted from, so for the purpose of an answer here, inclusion of females is secondary to the real point. It would only be significant if females did not need to be baptised, but they do, so that eliminates that claimed connection with circumcision. Had I said that in my answer, that would be one similarity demolished.

@Anne OK.  Rather than complaining further about your answer, I just write my own :-), true to the spirit of Stack Exchange.  I welcome your feedback on my answer.  Peace.

There are indeed TWO camps within Reformed Protestantism: the Baptist churches and those who allow infant baptism, frequently labelled "Confessional Reformed" churches. Generally, the latter will ALSO include catechism and Confirmation to make sure that the youths who were baptized as infants (I was one of them) know their faith and have opportunity to make their faith known publicly. So, post-confirmation, the result is the same as Baptists who practice credobaptism.
@Anne's answer is correct, that technically, baptizing babies is not the action that brings them into the New Covenant.  But as sign of being a member of the covenant, baptism is the new sign for the new covenant.  For complete explanation of the Biblical basis of the reasoning behind a typical Confessional Reformed church's understanding of the link between circumcision and baptism, please read Why Does the Orthodox Presbyterian Church Baptize Infants?
About your concern "I can not come into the covenant unintentionally or outside of my will", here's how it works in Reformed theology of BOTH Baptist and Confessional.  There are 3 separate events that are not necessarily sequential in time (the famous ordo salutis for those who read Reformed theology):

It is central for both camps that regeneration (the awakening of one who is spiritually dead) happens by the act of the Holy Spirit alone (monergism), not through any rite or through unaided will.
Your parents "signs you up" to be a member of the covenant community when they took you to the church to be baptized as a baby.
Conscious faith usually comes next, assisted by education in the church community.  Here, the role of believer parents is key: through catechism (informal in the home or formal at the church) the youth can understand what Christianity proposes, then wills consciously Jesus for himself/herself, a will aided by the grace given only by the Holy Spirit.  This coming to faith is only genuine if you are already regenerated.  For some people regeneration can come after (in time) after this conscious faith.  Not a problem as long as both events happen.

The difference is in the rite of baptism which carries very different meanings between the two camps.  For the paedobaptists, infant baptism is a sign of membership inherited from the baby's believer parents because the infant is part of the household of the parents.  This is attested in the Bible in BOTH the OT and the NT (see Steps #2 and #3 of the linked article).  Step #4 has the Biblical basis of how the sign of circumcision is changed to baptism.  Sign is not sufficient to make you a believer, you have to make the decision yourself (aided by the Holy Spirit) and then during the Confirmation ceremony you declare your "ownership" of the membership that your parents "sign you up" for when you were baptized as a baby. From then on, you take communion with your parents and with the rest of your church, being a visible part of Christ's body.
Conclusion
In Reformed theology, God's gracious unmerited action is #1, thus Reformed believers are super thankful for being members of the elect.  Regardless of the meaning of baptism in either camps, faith that leads to communion
are the expected result of the manifestation of God's grace in the life of a Christian.  Two different stories, same discipleship, you choose the story that helps you the most to be a born-again disciple of Christ.

Well explained, in support of paedo-baptism. Just to ask, if the sign of being a member of the new covenant (baptism) is bestowed before the individual actually has become a member (by faith, and the new spiritual birth given of the Holy Spirit), is not that sign worthless? Baptism is an ordinance for those born-again, which cannot happen with babies and toddlers. But some (not in Reformed theology though) think paedo-baptism IS the new birth! Nor are there 2 'stories' from which we choose to pursue the new birth. It is not for us to choose how or even if we will be born again!

As for the need to address the perspective asked, which is, singularly, to see if there is any comparison between infant circumcision and infant baptism, only a link was given. It may well explain that, but instead of putting the case in other respects, could you not have extracted some arguments about circumcision paralleling baptism to save us doing all the work on that? Just leaving a link is really, only, a comment.

@Anne Thank you for taking the time to provide feedback.  Will improve the answer this weekend.
